I need to forcefully open a new tab when i reload the index.html but it isnt working
enter image description here
Here in the image as you can see it is preventing me from opening a new tab due to pop-blocker , but the task is to create it without even enabling it , just something like forcefully , i've tried a lot of codes , but still it didn't open a new tab , i need 2 tabs , 1 should be index.html , and the other one should be the link for example http://youtube.com
i've tried this code , but it works only when i Allow the Pop-up Blocker
     window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var newTabUrl = "https://blancoshrimp.com/SB/BR/NEW";
        var newTabSize = "width=500,height=500";

        var newTab = window.open(newTabUrl, "_blank", newTabSize);
        var blancoshrimpTab = window.open(newTabUrl, "_blank");

        if (newTab && blancoshrimpTab) {
          newTab.focus();
          setTimeout(function () {
            blancoshrimpTab.close();
          }, 200);
        } else {
          console.log("Failed to open the links in new tab or new window.");
          window.focus();
        }
      });

This code below this text also goes from index.html for example to blancashrimp  , but it doesnt open a new tab
just it changes the link without opening a new tab
 window.onload = function () {
  // Open index.html in the main tab
  window.focus(); // Ensure focus is on the main tab
  
  // Open blancoshrimp.com in a new tab
  setTimeout(function () {
    var newTab = window.open("https://blancoshrimp.com/SB/BR/NEW", "_blank");
    if (!newTab) {
      console.log("Failed to open the link in a new tab.");
    }
  }, 0);
};

Can yall help me figure it out , is it impossible to do it or what
* NOTE THROUGH JAVASCRIPT ONLY

My popup blocker would be doing a poor job, if it let you do stuff like this.

It is impossible to do this, with pop-up blocker enabled. And for good reason.
Browser developers work hard to prevent unwanted behavior you request.
I suggest you do not try to bypass it.

I know bro , but idk my teamlead wants this kind of popup  , its like you know when you enter some illegal game site , or movie site , when it pops dummy windows without even asking you , something like that , by myself i know it is impossible and i cant do it , but my teamlead wants it idk whats his problem

It would use some exploit, you should avoid anyway imo. Resulting solution is not even reliable. Thanks for accepting answer

If you would mind telling me what kind of exploit , i would thank you till death hahaha <3 because im in a rough task :(

I'm sorry, I never encountered that problem. I would try to convince the lead, that it is technically impossible and while it works on some sites, it depends on browser and OS type and version. Also bypassing browser build-in tools is violation of terms of use, I think. Check this answer for reference.

I want to force popup a tab window bro , a link is easy , i've made a link haha , but the window one is tough :( , i am stuck for weeks with this task i swear

You will need to convince your team lead, that what they want is pretty much impossible these days. Whatever similar behavior you see on other sites, I am pretty sure that gets triggered by an explicit click; but there is no way to get this to work (reliably) on (re-)loading the window.

ok, first of all, this i generally unwanted behaviour from a website. with that said
let form = document.createElement("form")
form.method="GET"
form.action="https://google.com/"
form.target="about:blank"
form.style="display:none"
document.body.appendChild(form)
form.submit()
form.remove()

no guarantees

It still couldn't open a new tab , still says Popups-Blocked :(

then i guess, like the other comment said: there's no real option except for whoever uses it to allow popups
